# SQL Server Reporting Services installation and setup

Tags: sql-server-2008, configuration, reporting-services, installation

We have a single computer with Windows7 Home Premium running with SQL Server 2008 R2 and would like to install the Reporting Services on it.

Can you point us to a step by step tutorial or other web site (not microsoft) that will get this up and running?

We ran the SQL Server setup program and we did not see an option to install the Reporting Services.

We searched 2 ebooks already (the books did not tell us where to get the Reporting Services software) as well as looked at the Microsoft site which was way to overwhelming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0OJSzC_wcx8)? It's doing an install on a server, but the steps are the same. The critical step is the features selection, it's at the beginning of part 2.

Comment: Thanks for the video link. When I viewed the video it showed a different setup screen so I looked at the different versions of SQL Server 2008 express r2 and found the one called Advanced. The one I was using was the one with Tools and I did not know the Reporting Services was missing from that version. I'm starting to use the "Add Features" section of the Advanced version and hopefully the Reporting Services will get installed.

Answer (score 2):

You can have the steps needed from this page: [Setup SQL Reporting Services (SRS) in SQL 2008](http://www.desktopcontrol.info/2009/11/setup-sql-reporting-services-srs-in-sql.html) .